# Referencing data in stateless React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I made a stateless component with an internal variable to reference an input, as below. This is working fine.

```
const MyStatelessComp = ({ team, teamProgress, onSet, editing, enableEdit }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="team__goal-target_header" >Team's Savings Target</div>
      <div className="team__goal-target_value" >
        M$
        <input
          ref={ el => input = el }
          style={{width: '75px', border: 'none'}}
          onChange={() => onSet({teamId: team.id, goalValue: parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0}) }
        />
        <div
          ref={ el => input }
          style={{
            display: !input || (!isNaN(parseFloat(input.value)) && isFinite(input.value)) ? 'none' : 'block'
          }}
        >Must be numeric</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to validate input and display a notification `Must be numeric` is the anything that cannot be converted to a number is entered into my input field. That is not working however. How do I make `input` in the context of the "warning div" reference the value of the input?

Realize that this is not an unorthodox way to working with stateless components, but it would save me lots of pain.

Thank you.

Comment: Your component is not stateless anymore, the input's value is stateful. If stateless components do anything beyond calling callbacks, the paradigm doesn't really work anymore. Why would it save you lots of pain having it stateless? It's just a few lines more to turn it into a normal component with a controlled input.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a stateless component when he can be a simple statefull component ?

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const isNumber = !isNaN(this.state.value);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="team__goal-target_header">Team's Savings Target</div>
        <div className="team__goal-target_value">
          M$
          <input
            style={{ width: "75px", border: "none" }}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.value}
          />
          {isNumber ? "" : <div>Must be numeric</div>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can also toggle the div content or create a new alert component and toggle this component.